# newline doesn't work in LabelField

Tags: blackberry, newline, labelfield

I'm very confused. I've created a global variable:

```
public LabelField title2 = new LabelField("", 
    LabelField.ELLIPSIS | DrawStyle.HCENTER| LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH |
    Field.FIELD_VCENTER | LabelField.USE_ALL_HEIGHT);

...

title2.setText("blablablablablabla\nblablabalba");
```

But when i'm trying to show this text on device's display i see only one line instead of two.

[image]

but if i'm using

```
add(new LabelField("Line1\nLine2"));
```

it works properly. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What's your OS version/level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try skipping  `LabelField.ELLIPSIS` to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Oh man, you make my day. Thanks a lot. Sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

\n NEWLINE characters are not supported in `LabelField`s on OS 4.5.

They are supported in OS 5.0.

I do not have 4.6 & 4.7 environments setup on my machine to test with.

---

I just wanted to update this page for future search purposes, since I had the same problem as original poster and his answer was not working for me.